# Parallelizing nested for loops

Tags: parallelization, procedural-programming

I'm currently computing nested for loops.

I count up a few counting variables and compute a value for each set of counting variables, then that value is added to an array. It is a way of adding up the contributions of each of these counting variables.

It is something like this simplified code:

```
For[h = 1, h < hmax, h++, count1 = ((200/(hmax))*h);

For[j = 1, j < jmax, j++, count2 = ((100/(jmax))*j) ;


Value = ((user_defined_function1[count1-count2])^(2))*user_defined_function2[count2];

IArray =ReplacePart[IArray, index -> (IArray[[index]] + Value)  ] 

]]
```

The issue is that as my calculation has gotten more precise, I have found that I need many more counting variables. My new code has 6 nested for loops, instead of the 2 shown in this example. The code is taking too long.

I want to parallelize the calculation, since I have access to a machine with many slow cpu cores.

My first attempt will be replacing the For[] with Paralleldo[]. I read that Paralleldo[] has some complications if you call functions inside the Paralleldo[]. I don't think I understood the complication completely, so I am asking if there will be a problem if I proceed with replacing the for loops with Paralleldo[].

I think I can also reformulate the problem using ParallelTable[], but then the result will be in a different format and I will have to figure out how to extract the meaningful result. This extra work would not be ideal..

Can I use Paralleldo[] for this application? Are there problems? Are there better alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: In case you missed it: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica

Comment: Please format the post: put code in code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the info High Performance Mark! I will read up on it.

Comment: "I think I can also reformulate the problem using ParallelTable[]" Given that Mathematica uses the distributed-memory model, that is what you *should* do. "This extra work would not be ideal" You'd waste more time trying to work with `ParallelDo`. In the best case, your program will be much slower than what would have been possible. In the worst case, it will give you bad results (due to misunsderstandings about how parallelization works) and you'll waste a lot of time debugging it before you realize that `ParallelTable` was the way to go from the get go.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into ParallelTable. Thanks for sharing. I'm glad I asked when I first attempted to parallelize, instead of after wasting several days struggling and debugging.

Comment: Are there any caveats or subtleties that will make ParallelTable not work correctly for calculating user defined functions and editing a list? Can a single list be edited/updated within ParallelTable[] ?

Comment: "Can a single list be edited/updated within ParallelTable[]" No, it cannot. In Mathematica, the parallel threads do not share any memory, so they cannot modify the same list.  More precisely, accessing the same variable is possible with `SetSharedVariable`, but it comes with compromises. Every access will require a callback to the main kernel. If your "user defined functions" are very slow, then this might not be a big drawback. If not, then this will kill the performance.

Comment: The best approach is to formulate the algorithm in such a way that you do not need to modify the same variable from different parallel threads. If a current iteration of the loop does not need to access data produces in previous iterations, then this is always possible. For your code, I suggest collecting `index -> Value` pairs from the `Table`, then combining them at the very end. You could use `GroupBy` to collect values for identical indices, sum them up, then use a single call to ReplacePart (or better, use `SparseArray`)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it has a similar structure to this small example:

```
arr = ConstantArray[0, 5];
Do[
 Module[{index, value},
  index = Mod[i, 5, 1];
  value = i^2;
  arr = ReplacePart[arr, index -> arr[[index]] + value]
  ],
 {i, 100}
 ]
arr
```

Here each iteration of the loop modifies the variable `arr`. The key to effective parallelization in Mathematica is not to modify the same value from different parallel threads.

The code could be restructure like so:

```
(* generate index -> value pairs *)
rules = Table[Mod[i, 5, 1] -> i^2, {i, 100}];

(* combine them *)
Normal@SparseArray[
  Normal[Total /@ GroupBy[rules, First -> Last]],
  {5}
]
```

The idea is to first generate the `index -> value` pairs in a `Table` that can be easily changed to a `ParallelTable`, then combine them only when the parallel computation has finished.

[`ParallelCombine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelCombine.html) follows this principle, though in practice I often use `ParallelMap`/`ParallelTable`, then combine manually.

---

P.S. A slightly simpler, but undocumented way to combine the results is

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total];
Normal@SparseArray[rules]
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First];
```

It is very important that you don't forget to set this back to the default `First`, otherwise things may break.

Comment: thanks for the in depth answer. Before you wrote that, I think I came up with something similar. Is it correct that the main idea for this process is to use parallel processing to calculate the index->value pairs and then afterwards to perform the ReplacePart[] function separately (not using parallel operations)?